# why binding not working in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, angularjs-scope

```
  <div class="popover-content" ng-click="updateHeader('jack')">
```

When this div is clicked it calls a function which makes a get request and

---

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myContoller', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.username = "";
$scope.updateHeader = function(username) {

 var url = "api?user="+ username;
 $http.get(url)

 .then(function(response) {
   $scope.username = response.data.plugUser;
   console.log($scope.username);
   $scope.scrollableChatItems = response.data.msg;

       });
   };

};
```

---

Even though the console.log is working it is printing the username in the console, It is not updating in the username.why the username is not updating?

---

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="myController">
                    <h3 class="content-box-header">
                        {{username}}
                    </h3>
```

Comment: Is the "popover-content" div inside the "container" div with the ng-controller???

Comment: inside the ng-controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your div is placed inside the ng-controller div

```
   <div class="container" ng-controller="myController">
      <div class="popover-content" ng-click="updateHeader('jack')">
         <h3 class="content-box-header">
           {{username}}
        </h3>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks,It works.but why it was not working before.ng-init is for setting the default value.It has to called the function but why it is not setting the username

Answer (score 0):

Fix typo your controller name. myContoller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.username = "";
$scope.updateHeader = function(username) {

 var url = "api?user="+ username;
 $http.get(url)

 .then(function(response) {
   $scope.username = response.data.plugUser;
   console.log($scope.username);
   $scope.scrollableChatItems = response.data.msg;

       });
   };

};
```